Detect inactive group members as WhatsApp group manager
I manage a very large group in WhatsApp's web app.
Some of the group members are no longer active. As a result, group messages will never show as received (two checks) as there will always be some members who have not received them.
As the group manager, is there a way to detect which members can no longer receive messages?

To be clear there are three message statuses using checkmarks:
Message sent     Message Delivered     Message Read

You haven't defined "inactive" but, presumably, you mean they don't have WhatsApp installed on any device. If that's the case, the user will never have the  Message Delivered status.
You will not be able to easily determine whose messages are always "undelivered" for a large group using the native web app functionality.
You'd need to parse the message info pane, perhaps for a few messages that span a period of time, in order to compare it to your member list and note any member names that don't have any message status (missing) across those messages, because WhatsApp doesn't have a status for "not delivered."
Presumably, if they closed their account they would disappear from your group, so you would need to be careful about confusing users who are not using Whats App for a period of time from those never using it again.
To get the statuses, you may be able to MacGyver something by parsing the HTML. For example, if you paste the HTML from your group's full member list into Notepad++ you can extract the list of names using a find replace with the regular expression .*?role="gridcell".*? title="(.*?)" and the replacement $1\n. Adjusting this can address other needs.
However, given the size of your group, this is not likely to be a practical approach.  The web app dynamically loads content as needed when you scroll through the full group list as well as the message info pane meaning the underlying HTML changes as well.
Another approach is to take a look at the GitHub repo whatsapp-web.js. I haven't used it myself and am not affiliated, but it has been starred by about 14k GitHub users, appears actively maintained, and provides an API that you might use to pull the info you need.

pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js
A WhatsApp API client that connects through the WhatsApp Web browser app
The library works by launching the WhatsApp Web browser application and managing it using Puppeteer to create an instance of WhatsApp Web, thereby mitigating the risk of being blocked. The WhatsApp API client connects through the WhatsApp Web browser app, accessing its internal functions. This grants you access to nearly all the features available on WhatsApp Web, enabling dynamic handling similar to any other Node.js application.

Their website, wwebjs.dev, has links to the user guide, documentation, their Discord channel, etc.
